How to left align chemical equations with tags?
I have a set of chemical reactions I am trying to write using mhchem. I need to left-align the equations and right-align the tags. Here's what I have done so far:
\begin{align}
\ce{AB -> A + B} \label{R:R1}\tag{R1.1 - reaction1}\\
\ce{C + 2DE -> CD_2 + E_2} \label{R:R2}\tag{R1.2 - reaction2}\\
\ce{4FG -> 3F + FG_4} \label{R:R3}\tag{R1.3 - reaction3}    
\end{align}

When I use lalign, I get an error that \tag cannot be used here. This could be resolved if I write the chemical equations as regular equations. However, I prefer using mhchem. Is there a way around it?

If you don't use amsmath environments for math formulas, but just for chemical equations, you can use fleqn.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
\begin{gather}
\ce{AB -> A + B}           \label{R:R1}\tag{R1.1 -- reaction1}\\
\ce{C + 2DE -> CD_2 + E_2} \label{R:R2}\tag{R1.2 -- reaction2}\\
\ce{4FG -> 3F + FG_4}      \label{R:R3}\tag{R1.3 -- reaction3}    
\end{gather}
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
\begin{equation}
\ce{AB -> A + B} \label{x}\tag{whatever}
\end{equation}
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.

\end{document}


If instead you have equations to be centered, I suggest using nccmath and its fleqn environment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{reactions}{b}
 {\begin{fleqn}\begin{gather}#1\end{gather}\end{fleqn}}
 {\ignorespacesafterend}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{reaction}{}
 {\begin{fleqn}\begin{equation}}
 {\end{equation}\end{fleqn}\ignorespacesafterend}
\NewDocumentCommand{\reactiontag}{mm}{%
  % #1 = label, #2 = tag
  \label{#1}\tag{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
\begin{reactions}
\ce{AB -> A + B}           \reactiontag{R:R1}{R1.1 -- reaction1}\\
\ce{C + 2DE -> CD_2 + E_2} \reactiontag{R:R2}{R1.2 -- reaction2}\\
\ce{4FG -> 3F + FG_4}      \reactiontag{R:R3}{R1.3 -- reaction3}    
\end{reactions}
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
\begin{reaction}
\ce{AB -> A + B} \reactiontag{x}{whatever}
\end{reaction}
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.
Some text to show the margins.

\end{document}


I'd recommend using the latter syntax also in the case you have no equations to be centered, with easy redefinitions (just remove nccmath and the fleqn environments).
